# MySQL: Copy Multiple Values from random row of another table

Tags: mysql, random, sql-update

I have asked similar questions for Microsoft SQL Server and for PostGresql. Solutions which work there don’t work for MySQL.

I have two tables, `stuff` and `nonsense`. I would like to copy multiple values from a random row in `nonsense` to each row in `stuff`. Of course, there will be duplicates.

```
STUFF
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
| id | details | data        | more   |
+====+=========+=============+========+
| 1  | one     | (null)      | (null) |
| 2  | two     | (null)      | (null) |
| 3  | three   | (null)      | (null) |
| 4  | four    | (null)      | (null) |
| 5  | five    | (null)      | (null) |
| 6  | six     | (null)      | (null) |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+

NONSENSE
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | data    | more        |
+====+=========+=============+
| 1  | apple   | accordion   |
| 2  | banana  | banjo       |
| 3  | cherry  | cor anglais |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

I would like to be able to copy into the `stuff` table with something like:

```
UPDATE stuff SET data=?,more=?
FROM ?
```

I would like to get something like the following:

```
+-----+----------+---------+-------------+
| id  | details  | data    | more        |
+=====+==========+=========+=============+
| 1   | one      | banana  | banjo       |
| 2   | two      | apple   | accordion   |
| 3   | three    | apple   | accordion   |
| 4   | four     | cherry  | cor anglais |
| 5   | five     | banana  | banjo       |
| 6   | six      | cherry  | cor anglais |
+-----+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Here is a fiddle which works for PostgreSQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/313fb/8

If it were a single value, I could use a correlated subquery, but it won’t work properly for multiple values from the same row.

Newer PostGresql has the ability to copy into multiple columns from a correlated subquery. SQL Server the `OUTER APPLY` clause which allows a subquery in the FROM clause to  be correlated. Neither approach works for MySQL.

How can I copy multiple values from random rows in another table?

Comment: show the expected  result please

Comment: @scaisEdge See edit. The fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/313fb/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only have to do it once and do not care about real random, maybe invent a function, which somehow maps stuff.id to nonsense.id ?
for example:

```
update stuff s, nonsense n
set s.data = n.data, s.more = n.more 
where n.id = s.id + 1 or n.id = ceil(s.id/2) -1;
```

looks pretty much like crazy random to me ;)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0935/1

P.S. now, being serious... could not try it on sqlfiddle, but if you have access to mysql version 8.0+, you can try smth like the following:

```
with rn as (select n.data, n.more from stuff s, nonsense n order by rand())
update stuff, rn
set stuff.data = rn.data, stuff.more = rn.more;
```

UPDATE: after some collaborative brain storming two more variations were found

```
update stuff s 
join (select id,(select id from nonsense order by rand() limit 1) as nid from stuff) sq on s.id=sq.id 
join nonsense n on n.id = sq.nid 
set s.data = n.data, s.more = n.more;


update stuff s 
join (select * from (select s.id as sid, n.data as sdata, n.more as smore from stuff s, nonsense n order by rand()) sn group by sn.sid) sgr on s.id = sgr.sid 
set s.data = sgr.sdata, s.more = sgr.smore;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a pretty sight, but I think this is a solution.

Begin with a virtual table with the `stuff.id` and a random `nonsense.id`:

```
select id,(select id from nonsense order by rand() limit 1) as nid from stuff;
```

Join the `stuff` table with this virtual table as a subquery:

```
stuff s
join
(select id,(select id from nonsense order by rand() limit 1) as nid from stuff) sq
on s.id=sq.id
```

Update `s.data` and `s.more` with correlated subqueries:

```
set
    s.data=(select data from nonsense where id=sq.nid),
    s.more=(select more from nonsense where id=sq.nid);
```

This gives:

```
update
    stuff s
    join
    (select id,(select id from nonsense order by rand() limit 1) as nid from stuff) sq
    on s.id=sq.id
set
    s.data=(select data from nonsense where id=sq.nid),
    s.more=(select more from nonsense where id=sq.nid);
```

There should be a smoother solution, but this is the best I can do.

Comment: great! maybe putting an extra join on nonsense and so getting rid of two correlated subqueries will improve the execition time? update
    stuff s
    join
    (select id,(select id from nonsense order by rand() limit 1) as nid from stuff) sq
    on s.id=sq.id
    join nonsense n on n.id = sq.nid
set s.data = n.data, s.more = n.more;

Comment: just invented another one, but its probably not a great improvement... you should check it on big data: update stuff s join
(select * from 
(select s.id as sid, n.data as sdata, n.more as smore from stuff s, nonsense n order by rand()) sn
group by sn.sid) sgr 
on s.id = sgr.sid
set s.data = sgr.sdata, s.more = sgr.smore;

Comment: @InnaTichman I’ve tried both of these solutions, and they’re very good. The second one relies on a non-standard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`, but that’s fine. Can you add these to your answer below, so I can accept it all? Thanks

Comment: after all, it was your solution in the first place, which inspired my variations... but thank you!